# Select Multiple images from phone's gallery using phonegap

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am using phonegap to select images from device's photo gallery.The code I am using is

```
onclick="pickFromPhotoGallery(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY)"
```

and

```
function pickFromPhotoGallery(source){
navigator.camera.getPicture(getImageURI, function(){}, { quality: 50, 
  destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: source });
```

}

This allows me to select only one image at a time. I want to select multiple images at a time. 
Is there a way to do this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no way to do this. Please open an enhancement request on JIRA.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB

Comment: Thank you for your response.I guess there is already an enhancement request for this(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1215). Is there a workaround by any chance?